# input and select have different vertical positions in the same line

Tags: css

I use the floating labels from this [site](https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/rzroyJ).
I modified the code slightly to get put an input and a select in one row. In Edge Version 114.0.1823.67 and in Chrome Version 114.0.5735.199 the baselines have different vertical positions.
[image]
In Firefox Version 115.0 the baselines have the same vertical position.
[image]
Code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?selection.family=Lato');
 :root {
  --main-color: #ee6e73;
  --second-color: #333;
  --input-color: #9e9e9e;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

form h1 {
  color: var(--second-color);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.form-group input,
select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--input-color);
  color: var(--second-color);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-group label {
  color: var(--input-color);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  left: 0px;
}

.form-group input:focus,
.form-group select:focus {
  border-bottom-color: var(--main-color);
  outline: none;
}

.form-group input:valid+label,
.form-group input:focus+label {
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

input[type="button"] {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

input[type="button"]:active {
  border-color: #fff;
}

input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>CSS Floating Labels</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" required/>
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select>
          <option value="">Test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" required/><label>Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I tried to solve it with `vertical-position: bottom` but unfortunately without success.

Comment: Seems like a lot of CSS just to force the user to be surprised with some "non-standard" UI to me.

Answer (score 1):

`select` is notorious for challenging styling.  That being said I changed the padding - might need to even do a browser specific style but here I just changed the padding: `padding:  1.225em 0;`
FWIW I used `em` to help my brain work with things easier.

---

UPDATE: A totally different alternative to use a set of `grid` since we want both X and Y placement to put the labels and the fields on the same place on the row.  Note I named the row/column and used that.
Some wrappers and classes (I don't like using element tags in CSS styling so we can change the element type and not have to change the CSS)

- Made the button a `<button>`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?selection.family=Lato');
 :root {
  --main-color: #ee6e73;
  --second-color: #333;
  --input-color: #9e9e9e;
}

html,
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  /* assumed you want to super center the form */
  display: grid;
  /* same as center of both align/justify ref
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items */
  place-items: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.form-form {
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* fieldset takes whatever space is left over - 1fr */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1em auto;
  grid-template-areas: "formheader" "forminputs" "." "formbutton";
  align-items: center;
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-form .form-header {
  grid-area: formheader;
  color: var(--second-color);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 0.625em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em;
}

.fieldset-container {
  grid-area: forminputs;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  /* width of each field/column */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 18.75em);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--input-color, #00FF00);
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.form-group {
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  /*padding-bottom: 1.25em;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [only-one] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [form-things] auto 1fr;
  /* we COULD use the areas but we want to put them in the same line */
  grid-template-areas: "labels" "inputs";
}

.form-group .form-group-label {
  /* could also use the named line/row */
  grid-area: labels;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  color: var(--input-color);
  font-weight: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.form-group .form-group-input {
  /* we named the line/column so use that not the "area" name */
  /*  grid-area: inputs;*/
  grid-row-start: form-things;
  grid-column-start: only-one;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: var(--second-color);
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

.form-group .form-group-input:focus,
{
  border-bottom-color: var(--main-color);
  outline: none;
}

.form-group .form-group-input:valid~label,
.form-group .form-group-input:focus~label {
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-size: 0.875em;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.form-button {
  grid-area: formbutton;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
  /* made bigger as the 2px did not really show */
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3em;
  /* moved to grid as a row but not named area "."
 margin-top: 1em;*/
}

.form-button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.form-button:active {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.form-button:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-form">
  <h1 class="form-header">CSS Floating Labels</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="fieldset-container">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="form-input-1" class="form-group-input" type="text" required/>
        <label for="form-input-1" class="form-group-label">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <label class="form-group-label">TesterOut</label> -->
        <select class="form-group-input">
          <option value="">Test</option>
          <option value="water">Water</option>
          <option value="milk">Milk</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-group-input" type="password" required/><label class="form-group-label">Password</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button class="form-button" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that too. Now I have the gap in Firefox

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer I suspected but did not have time to test - you are going to have to put some browser specific  CSS detection in place methinks similar to what I did here - sorry I don't have time right now to dive into this deeper

Comment: FWIW before you go about doing feature detection for the CSS you might want to re-think and clarify the original CSS intent and what you are trying to do in the first place (which already appears somewhat non-standard) What I mean is perhaps create an actual label for the select and put that label above rather than the first option

Comment: You're right. I removed the transition and put the label above the select and input fields ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/qv7rb6cx/)). But the problem with the different vertical positions in different browsers (firefox) still remains.

Comment: Updated to use a set of grid layouts to accomidate the X and Y placement ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Grid_layout_using_named_grid_lines for naming lines of a grid